# "MODULE already defined" when compiling Android 4.3 source code

Tags: compiler-errors, android-source, android-4.3-jelly-bean

I downloaded the newest Android source code with repo, and attempted to compile it.
An error message printed when I ran `make -j4`.
Detail following:

`build/core/base_rules.mk:130: *** external/webrtc/src/system_wrappers/source: MODULE.TARGET.STATIC_LIBRARIES.libwebrtc_system_wrappers already defined by external/webrtc/src/system_wrappers/source.  Stop.`

Comment: If @mitchtech answer is correct, you must accept it. I am pretty sure it is correct because it worked for me. Thx.

Answer (score 15):

Apparently there is a bug in the webrtc makefiles that causes it to ignore including `STL` if the `NDK_ROOT` environmental variable is previously defined (by `~/.bashrc`, in my case). So just make sure `NDK_ROOT` is not defined at all when building. You can temporarily unset it with this command:

```
unset NDK_ROOT
```